# Django admin: reverse select foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to add pre-existing foreignkey items from the parent's admin. I have a "Bundle" model to hold "Product" items; many-to-one/foreignkey:

**models.py**

```
class Bundle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    bundle = models.ForeignKey(
        'Bundle',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

Below, I used StackedInline but this is for creating new products with a form:

**admin.py**

```
class ProductInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Product

@admin.register(Bundle)
class BundleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ProductInline,
        ]
```

Instead, I want to repeatedly add existing products from a dropdown/search in the Bundle section of admin. So, I make a Bundle and then add a series of Products from a dropdown / with a search.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For you requirement, you can use `ManyToManyField` in `Bundle` model instead of `ForeignKey` in `Product` model.
Check below code.

```py
class Bundle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ManyToManyField('Product')


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Then you can register admin interfaces:

```py
admin.site.register(Bundle)
admin.site.register(Product)
```

Then you can add series of `Product` from a dropdown/search.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I thought given it was a many to one relationship that I could do it with foreignkey but, sure, I'll just do manytomany. I'm surprised a reverse search isn't inbuild on a foreignkey but ok. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidMurphy in Django there is no Many to One relationship. if my answer helpful, please mark it as accepted answer. Thanks